# How to use composer with phpbrew?

Tags: php, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04, phpbrew

I installed phpbrew to use php 5.4 in Ubuntu 14.04. It works fine, except when I try to use composer, which ignores phpbrew and installs dependencies related to php 5.5.

Is there a way to force composer to be compatible with phpbrew config? 
I trying to add: php: "5.4" in my composer.json, but it says that this requirement is not possible with my php version.

Answer (score 7):

You can easy install composer with phpbrew by following command:

```
$ phpbrew app get composer
```

Source: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew Section: Installing Extra Apps

Comment: Looks like they have now removed `phpbrew app`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting an error as `app` is not a valid command. To fix this, I used `brew install composer`.